# Windows 10 update from 1703 to 1803 (skip 1709) offline

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1803

After searching alot i was unable to find a proper solution.
My situation is something like this.
I am on build 1703 (15063.674) and i want to upgrade it to 1803. Skipping version 1709.
I want to do this offline as i have limited data. I have enough data to download builds but windows update is slow (stops for no reason sometimes) and doesn't manage data well. So the only option left to me is offline.
Tried windows 10 update assistant but it gets stuck mid-way and fails to resume. My bad luck is a major ongoing factor.
I can download from Microsoft catalogue.
Do i have to first install cumulative updates for 1703?
After that direct update to 1803?
Sorry for all the trouble.
Just guide me into the general direction.
Thanks

Comment: You can use Windows Media Creator to make an installation USB, boot from it and update.

Comment: update to Windows 10 1803 and skip 1709 can achieve through using an available Windows 10 1803 ISO disk, Download from Microsoft website to a USB disk, and install it again. As your last time use Windows update assistent fail, we should turn off antivirus temporarily and check again. As antivirus software will prevent to replace some system components.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, in fact you can go from any build specifically to the latest.

All you need to do is download the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) and run it on a pc with sufficient bandwidth. It will then ask you if you want to update the current pc, or that you want to create an offline installer. You select the offline installer. You can then save it to an .ISO file or write it directly to a USB stick that can be booted from. If you have that stick ready, using the USB stick method is recommended.

After the stick has been downloaded, this becomes your installation medium for that specific version of windows. From any version of windows, you can upgrade to this version using that usb stick, although you cannot downgrade from a later version of windows to this version.

If your computer does not already have windows, you can boot from the stick to install a fresh copy of windows, directly to this version. But you mentioned you already have windows installed.

In that case, from within windows, plug in the usb stick. Browse the stick and launch setup (if it doesn't already launch by itself). It will ask you if you want to upgrade windows to the version that is on the stick and keep your files and everything in tact.

Sidenote, the USB stick can be used to troubleshoot pc's from which windows can't boot anymore.

Comment: If download gets stuck or i cross my data limit can it be resumed?

Comment: @AlkeshLabana , I don't think so for the Media Creation Tool specifically.  There may be other ways of getting the ISO with resume possible.  For instance, I used to be able to download ISOs from Microsoft Volume Licensing through my company.  I don't suggest torrenting it because there's no guarantee that the file you get is the real thing.

Comment: No, the download cannot be resumed. It will fail and you have to do it again which will start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest finding a place where you can get unlimited data.  A friend with a dedicated Internet line, for instance.  In the USA, public libraries, coffeeshops, hotels, and many other places often have free wifi.  You can use the Media Creation Tool there to save the ISO, and then burn it to a DVD or thumb drive at your leisure.  Alternately, you can just run Windows Update normally while present in the free spot.

Comment: I got my windows through a retailer. And it's volume licence copy under him that's why if i install any other iso it might not work (might get "activate windows"). So trying to go through  Microsoft catalogue. I might give media creation a try tomorrow.

Comment: @AlkeshLabana if you have windows installed and you perform an upgrade, it doesn't really matter what ISO you have, as long as it is the same version, and it will upgrade and keep your license key in tact. A reinstall should do the same as long as it is the same version.